# Can a website be completely secure?

Tags: security

Of course, there is always an possibility to get in, I guess.

But how far can you go with securing a website, and how safe will it finally be? Can you guarantee nobody without the right authorisation gets in, or can you never be sure enough?

I'm curious to your answers!

Comment: You answered the question on the first line of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Everything designed by humans can be cracked by humans. The right way to do it, is to do **risk management**, where `risk = damage * probability` . Make sure you have backups and you can handle a break-in without going bankrupt. Bruce Schneier has written a lot about security and how to handle it correctly. A valuable place to start is his blog. [This post](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/08/five_neglects_i.html) might be of interest for you.

(Btw, this is off-topic and belongs somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

I read a book recently that talking about web security, it is really a good starting point  if you want to know more on security: The Title is ["Tangled Web; A Guide to Securing Modern Web Applications"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593273886) by Michal Zalewski

If you want an answer, I think that a web site is not secure by default, there are so many technologies around a web site:
- web server 
- scripting (php, javascript, many years ago applet java)
- databases
- CSS, XHTML, HTML5